# Is there a way to access photo albums from public link?

Tags: node.js, express, google-photos, google-photos-api

I'm creating a web application that accesses your photos. In order to make my application accessible to anyone who doesn't have a google account, I would like to allow the application to read and edit photos from public albums using their shared URL. This seems like something that should be easy to do, since all the authentication already happened when you made the album public, however, there doesn't seem to be any documentation about this online.

I've looked online for this but no information was there. Right now I'm writing my application in Node.js and working on authenticating with OAuth. I hope that there is something similar to the google maps API so that I don't need to provide authentication to edit a public album. If I have to use OAuth, then I can but I figured accessing a public album shouldn't be very difficult.

Thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not.

I have an application (in PHP) that connects to Google Photos through the API (after OAuth), and you could only get public link of albums created by the same application, not the ones created before, even you make it public from the Google Photos User Interface.